# Sql dropdown query

Tags: sql

I have the following code: `SELECT DISTINCT [id] As Value, [ServerName] As Text FROM [dbo].[DominoDB]` that is executed on dapper in C# project, to populate a dropdown. I want to have in the dropdown only distinct ServerNames, but in the database table DominoDB i have rows like these: id = 1 ServerName = dominoDB and id = 2 ServerName = dominoDB and as a result in the dropdown i have duplicated names of servers. Can anyone help me to have only distinct server names?

Comment: Add the correct dbms tag please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ServerName] As Text FROM [dbo].[DominoDB]
```

And if You need also Value, You can't use distinct for both fields. You must decide if value must be the greatest ID or the smallest one. Then Group by Server name and use MAX/MIN on ID field.

If You choose that option with MIN id:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as VALUE, [ServerName] As Text FROM [dbo].[DominoDB] GROUP BY ServerName
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, the Select query i posted works (it populates the dropdown, but with duplicated server names), how should i construct it to give only distinct server names?

Comment: You have to understand that IF You need also ID, and Distinct server name You have to decide what ID You want to pick, cause Your ServerName = dominoDB have two values '1' and '2'.

Comment: I see, but how can i add a id column in the select statement? If i try :

Comment: SELECT [id] As Value, DISTINCT  [ServerName] As Text FROM [dbo].[DominoDB] i have an exception!

Comment: SELECT MIN(ID) as VALUE,  [ServerName] As Text  FROM [dbo].[DominoDB] GROUP BY ServerName

Comment: I told You can't just select ID, because You have 2 ID for one record. IF You want to have distinct servername, You have to decide Which ID TO PICK.

Comment: Yeah @JanWalczak is right. You cannot have distinct servername because of your  id column. For your Distinct work, both the rows HAVE to be the same

Comment: Thanks, i understand your query and it hepled me for my problem